# Way to detect broken images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to detect if an image is broken and replace with a default image if the image link is broken.  I know i could do this with an image proxy, but was hoping to do it on the fly with javascript.

Comment: Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe it's the `onerror` event of the `img` element. `onerror=function(){}` though i've never used it.

Comment: Is it working in all browsers? Related info is missing in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Answer (score 6):

As any event the `onerror` will propagate upwards on the DOM, so you could make a generic handler for this type of errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).bind('error', function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.src);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `<img onerror='doWhateverFunction()'` etc etc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197053(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Really nifty way of doing this!

Answer (score 0):

Example of code:

```
<script language='javascript'>
function defaultImage(img)
{
    img.onerror = "";
    img.src = 'default.gif';
}
</script>
<img alt="My Image" src="someimage.gif" onerror="defaultImage(this);" />
```

Comment: In the usual case - this will work fine. But I'm fairly sure this will cause an infinite loop if `default.gif` is also broken/not found. That's why in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images the AC response set img.onerror to blank in the defaultImage function

Comment: this should be `img.target.src = default.gif`