# How can I detect a broken link when setting a background image on a div component in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
<div className="image" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${entity.image_url})`}} />}
```

I am setting a background-image by passing the url as an inline style attribute. However, there will be times when the image link is broken. I am familiar with the onerror event of the  tag. However I am not familiar with how I can detect a broken link when setting a background image. I was thinking of attempting to load the image in a hidden  and use the onerror attribute, but this requires me to load the image twice, which is wasteful. What is a better way to do this?

Comment: i have to ask the obvious question. why not just use local images?

Comment: Good question, I cannot because I am consuming paginated data from an API

Answer (score 1):

The old school style is to pre load all images.
[Preload Images](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)

Now you has the Image in a js object and does not to load the image again or twice. By this you can also check if its broken [Detect broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495260/way-to-detect-broken-images-in-javascript). And for sure if you use the clever AJAX way of life you can also detect and replace broken images.

Comment: Just a tip. if you store the images in  in  a fake frameset (just one frame) they will remain even your page content changes. Some thought also by  https://www.photo-mark.com/notes/image-preloading/. BTTW: are you sure that your browser doesnt cache them ?

Answer (score 1):

why not write some JS and test the entity.image_url. if you don't get an object back it will come up as undefined or null. wrtie an if statement for both to cover the possibilities.

```
if (entity === undefined || entity === null) {
  //write an error message
} else {
  //drop a dynamic template literal into your html
  //you can either appendChild() or build a string and user innerHTML
}
```

Comment: That seems to be the easiest route to go. What I am trying to do is add a fallback image like so: <div className="image" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${entity.image_url})`, url('image'}} />}

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was able to do it in React:

```
 import noImage from <local_image_path>;

 {(entity && entity.image) ?
    <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${entity.image}), url(${noImage})`}}/> :
    <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${noImage})`}}/>
  }
```

This takes care of two cases. Case 1: broken image link. If there is a 404 on the entity.image url, noImage is loaded. Case 2: entity.image is undefined, noImage is loaded.